# Why does marker disappear when I remove static field?

Tags: gazebo-11, physics

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Disclaimer- new to gazebo, but familiar with ROS/C++

gazebo-11

I am trying to add a model to gazebo of a marker so I can add a plugin to move that marker. However, when I remove the static field, the marker is no longer visible, though there aren't errors when launched. Here are the relevant fields:

In the launch file:

> ```
>  <include file="$(find
> >      gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
> >      <arg name="world_name" value="$(find
>  marker_detection_tests)/world/robotic_floor.world"/>
> <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
> >     <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
> <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
> >     <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
> <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
> >     <arg name="verbose" value="$(arg verbose)"/>   </include>
> ```

In the .world file:

```
<include>
  <name>tag_1</name>
    <uri>model://tag</uri>
   <pose>2 0 0.001 0 0 0</pose>
</include>
```

sdf file:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.6'>
  <model name="tag">
    <pose>0 0 0.00  0 0 0</pose>
<static>false</static>
<link name="tag0">
  <inertial>
    <mass>0.01</mass>
<inertia>
  <ixx>0.000083</ixx>
  <ixy>0</ixy>
  <ixz>0</ixz>
  <iyy>0.00015</iyy>
  <iyz>0</iyz>
  <izz>0.000083</izz>
</inertia>
</inertial>
  <visual name="visual">
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.3 0.3 0.01</size>
   </box>
    </geometry>
        <material>
            <script>
              <uri>model://tag/materials/scripts</uri>
              <uri>model://tag/materials/textures</uri>
              <name>Tag0Texture/Diffuse</name>
            </script>
        </material>
      </visual>
    </link>
    <!--plugin name="marker_controller_plugin" filename="libmarker_controller_plugin.so"/-->
  </model>
</sdf>
```

When the static variable is true, this marker is visible, but when false or completely removed it is not visible anywhere in the world from what I can tell. Having the plugin on or commented out has no affect right now. I have also tried removing the inertials and mass, moving the sdf contents into the world, removing all but the pose in the world. There don't seem to be many examples on this, I'm only seeing one which doesn't give much variation. I'm suspicious of something happening with physics in the world that I'm unaware of. I would appreciate any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29199/why-does-marker-disappear-when-i-remove-static-field?/) by [ari](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/192979/ari/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It seemed what I was missing was adding a collision field. For instance, by adding:

```
  <collision name="collision">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>0.3 0.3 0.01</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
```

after the inertial end tag, it made it so my marker was not falling through the floor.

---

Originally posted by [ari](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/192979/ari/) with karma: 1 on 2023-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0